# How to create subtable in md-table in Angular Material 2?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I need to create subtable (table or `md-table`, please see picture) in `md-table`. I use Angular 4.2.4 and Angular Material 2.0.0-beta.8. I could put my table only in the cell but not in a row. I played somehow with it 
[here](https://plnkr.co/edit/7OpGG1SruPaD1WwNXu3J?p=preview) (an example is based on official example).

How can I solve this?

[image: subtable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding closed [issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6597) on GitHub it's impossible now and no plans to change it in future.